# Resizing QRCode from base64 png in PHP

Tags: php, image

I get a QRCode png as base64 from a remote service and need to display it on the web. When blowing the picture up without the "vector" data, it blurs:

[image]

I write the base64 to disk with

```
fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($this->getQRCode()));
```

The resulting png is a bit small (29x29 pixels). When I open it with e.g. Photoshop, I can blow it up without loss so it looks like the "vector" data is intact. Note the "pixels":

[image]

How can I do this on the server side before writing it down to disk and linking to it from the web.

Comment: It's either a PNG or a vector image, not both. Doesn't the webservice provide an option to set the image size?

Comment: @miken32: right, it's a png but somehow photoshop manages to blow it up like the 2nd image. I wonder how... WS provides no option on the image size...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you are "blowing the picture up." Have you tried rescaling the image in PHP?

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$bigimage = imagescale($image, 128, 128, IMG_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
//dumps directly to output
imagepng($bigimage, null, 0);
```

Edit: you can try various interpolation modes [as specified here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetinterpolation.php), if `IMG_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR` isn't suitable. (Also, note the British/Canadian spelling of neighbour.)

Answer (score 0):

The old school way of blowing up images was to (ideally) double pixels. Smoothing the rough edges that were the result of that process was invented later. So now I go with this:

```
imagescale($image, 128, 128, IMG_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR);
```